# Nullpointerexception in android fragment manager

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have a code to recreate the map such as:

```
public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();    

        if (this.f != null
                && getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        this.f.getId()) != null) {
             Log.i("DESTROY VIEW MAP", "MAP!!!!!!!!!!!"+f);
             myFragmentManagerSupport.beginTransaction().remove(this.f).commit();
             Log.i("DESTROY VIEW MAP 222222222222222", "MAP!!!!!!!!!!!"+f);
           // this.f = null;
            Log.i("DESTROY VIEW MAP 333333333333333333", "MAP!!!!!!!!!!!"+f);
        }

    }
```

But i am having the force close when i go back from this section. I have got error in the code

```
myFragmentManagerSupport.beginTransaction().remove(this.f).commit();
```

When i commented the code ,no issue is there.

Can anyone help me for that?

Comment: You are using two type of fragmentmanager why ?

Comment: Where i have used two type of fragment manager???

Comment: myFragmentManagerSupport and getFragmentManager()

Comment: Its not two type public static FragmentManager myFragmentManagerSupport;

Comment: Can you add some more code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same fragmentManager object 
public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

```
    if (this.f != null
            && myFragmentManagerSupport().findFragmentById(
                    this.f.getId()) != null) {
         Log.i("DESTROY VIEW MAP", "MAP!!!!!!!!!!!"+f);
         myFragmentManagerSupport.beginTransaction().remove(this.f).commit();
         Log.i("DESTROY VIEW MAP 222222222222222", "MAP!!!!!!!!!!!"+f);
       // this.f = null;
        Log.i("DESTROY VIEW MAP 333333333333333333", "MAP!!!!!!!!!!!"+f);
    }

}
```